# OSMDroid setMaxZoomLevel without the last level of zoom

Tags: android, zooming, osmdroid

I'm working on a project with OSMDroid, online mode and offline works fine. Offline mode works with files for a zoom level from 13 to 18.
I did not find any information about whether it is possible to zoom to 19 without tuilles Level 19, ie zoom in on tuilles level 18?
Currently if I put map.setUseDataConnection (false); map.setMaxZoomLevel (19) with max lvl 18 tuilles in the zip file, when I zoom to 19, the tuille displayed on the screen is enlarged but when I slide on the screen other tuilles are no longer displayed .

If someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to automatically scale your tiles from zoom level 18 (although it has been proposed), so if your offline maps don't have level 19 then you won't see any tiles at that zoom level. You will see all on-screen tiles from 18 (which are in the cache) temporarily scaled up as a visual effect, but it won't scale tiles elsewhere in the zoom level.